# React JS Reducers Prop data after fetch

Tags: reactjs, redux

A tried the Reducers and the Actions for a simple login to see how react actually works, i create a component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import Empty from '../Layouts/Empty';
import { Button } from '../UI/Button';
import Loading from '../Helpers/Loading';
import { actionCreators } from '../../actions';
import Notifications, {notify} from 'react-notify-toast';

class LoginForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        isLoading: false
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    this.props.dispatch(actionCreators.login(this.state));
    console.log(this.props.isFetching);
    console.log(this.props.error);
    console.log(this.props.auth);
  }

  render() {

    const {email, password, isLoading} = this.state;  
    return (
            <Empty>
                <div className='main'>
                    <Notifications />                    
                </div>
                <h1>Welcome Again</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="email@domain.com" name="email" value={email} className="form-control" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="***********" name="password" value={password}  className="form-control" onChange={this.onChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group form-group-button">                    
                        <button type="submit" className="button button-primary button-right button" style={{width: "100%"}} disabled={isLoading}>LOGIN</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div className="form-description">
                    <Button to='#' classes="button-block button-google">Login using Google+</Button>
                    <Button to='#' classes="button-block button-facebook">Login using Facebook</Button>
                </div>
            </Empty>
    );
  }
}


LoginForm.propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func,
    isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    error: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default connect((store) => {
    return {
        isFetching: store.loginState.isFetching,
        error: store.loginState.error,
        auth: store.loginState.auth
  };
})(LoginForm)
```

My reducer:

```
import { FETCHING_AUTH_SUCCESS, FETCHING_AUTH_FAILURE, FETCHING_AUTH } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    data: [],
    dataFetched: false,
    isFetching: false,
    error: false,
    auth: false
}

export default function loginReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCHING_AUTH:
            return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: true,
            error: false,
            auth: false
            }
        case FETCHING_AUTH_FAILURE:
            return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: false,
            error: true,
            auth: false
            }
        case FETCHING_AUTH_SUCCESS:
            return {
            isFetching: false,
            dataFetched: true,
            data: action.data,
            error: false,
            auth: true
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

And my action:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as types from './types';

export function login(data) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: types.FETCHING_AUTH
    });
    fetch('MY_URL', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        if(response.token != ""){
          dispatch({
            type: types.FETCHING_AUTH_SUCCESS,
            data: response,
            error: false,
            auth: true
          });
        }

      }).catch((response) => {
        dispatch({
          type: types.FETCHING_AUTH_FAILURE,
          data: response,
          error: true,
          auth: false
        });
      });
  }
}
```

When i submit the form whit the data the POST are correctly and i get the response.
My question is about in the reducer i have FETCHING_AUTH_SUCCESS, and the params:

```
return {
            isFetching: false,
            dataFetched: true,
            data: action.data,
            error: false,
            auth: true
            }
```

if i print the object it's ok, but how can i get that "auth" is it true?
Because when i submit the Form and print on the handler the atributes.

```
console.log(this.props.isFetching);
console.log(this.props.error);
console.log(this.props.auth);
```

It always return false when i suppose that might be "true" and i want to show that actually the Login was succesfully.

What am i missing?

Regards.

Comment: My guess is you forgot to add your reducer on store, put some console message inside your reducer and ensure that message appear during fetching flow.

Comment: Actually on the reducer enter on the case of "FETCHING_AUTH_SUCCESS" and the data might be set on the params, but on the component how know if the props changes and validate it?

Comment: You are using `react-redux`, so each time your state changes, your component will be rendered again. Check if render function is called when state changes, if don't, is because your state didn't changed. Also, ensure you added `<Provider>` from `react-redux` on top of your components hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, you're right my problem was that the type of the data wasn't correct so always the default value.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the code below the `login` action is `async`. So props won't get updated synchronously.

```
this.props.dispatch(actionCreators.login(this.state));
console.log(this.props.isFetching);
console.log(this.props.error);
console.log(this.props.auth);
```

Once `FETCHING_AUTH_SUCCESS` is dispatched and and the component receives new props, it will get reflected.

Comment: When i print on console where the reducers is entering, i can see that actually is on the case of "FETCHING_AUTH_SUCCESS" but, how on the component if is async can i show the alert?